# Could anyone tell me what font this is?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

[image]
I came across this font and I really want to use it. Does anyone know it?

Comment: Have you tried calling them and asking? http://lukesgeneralstore.ca/

Comment: I'd say it's custom, but then I noticed the L is thicker than the rest...which is usually a tell-tale sign of "fake" small caps. So this very well could be a font. The 'S' feels a bit wonky. Could be a freebie font.

Comment: Hi, welcome to graphicdesignSE! There are two different fonts in the image, can you specify which one you're asking? Or crop the image to show only the one you're referring to.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't enough characters to make the best assessment of the font. But tools such as the following may get you very close:

[WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont)

[Identifont](http://www.identifont.com)

Try ignoring the shadow as it may or may not be part of the font family.